# Numpy with complex numbers and +=

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, complex-numbers, numpy-ufunc

I found something strange while working with complex matrices in python using numpy. I'll just make a short example to explain it:

This code is working totally fine:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2, 2))
b = np.array([[1j, 1j], [1j, 2]])

a = a + b

print(a)
```

with output

```
[[0.+1.j 0.+1.j]
 [0.+1.j 0.+1.j]]
```

But if I change the a = a + b to a += b (how I usually do it), it's giving me an error.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2, 2))
b = np.array([[1j, 1j], [1j, 1j]])

a += b

print(a)
```

with error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Where does this come from? I just want to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes from the fact that `numpy` is overriding functions. In regular Python, the following two statements are equivalent:

```py
a = a + b
a += b
```

However, with `numpy` this is **not** the case. With `numpy`, it is often very important to distinguish whether a new array is created or the original array is modified.

When you run `a = a + b`, what this does is create a *new* array and store that back in `a`.

When you run `a += b`, what this does is try to modify the *original* `a` array with `b`. However, since `a` is of type `float` and `b` is of type `imaginary`, this modification is illegal.